# Typeset R character vectors

Tags: loops, r, sweave, knitr

I have two vectors in `R` that I want to typeset. The first vector includes the titles and the second the body texts.

Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<data>>=
title <- c("1","2","3","4")
body <- c("one","two","three","four")
@

% Expected result in TeX
% 
% 1
% one
%
% 2
% two
% 
% 3
% three
%
% 4
% four


\end{document}
```

This task requires a loop but I am not sure whether I should prepare the `TeX` markdowns directly in the `R` chunk with the option `results=asis` or whether I should use a combination of `\forloop` and `\rinline{x}` directly in `TeX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure is the most elegant solution. But it works.

```
<<r-loop, echo=FALSE, results='asis', warning=FALSE>>=
for (i in 1:length(title)) {
  cat(title[i])
  cat(body[i])
}
@
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just `paste()` the two vectors along with an empty character vector, and pass the result to `\rinline{}`.

```
\rinline{paste(title, body, '', sep = '\n', collapse = '\n')}
```

You can certainly do this in a code chunk with `results='asis'`. The two approaches are basically equivalent.